# How to query entries using a waterfall effect or logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a query that filters in order of hierarchy

In table `IDBANK`, there are only three columns, `ID`, `ALIAS_ID` and `ALIAS_ID_CD`.

Each `ID` can have several `ALIAS_ID`s while each `ALIAS_ID` will contain one `ALIAS_ID_CD`. For example, if `ALIAS_ID` begins with an A, then the `ALIAS_ID_CD` will be A.

I would like to query from `IDBANK` all unique `ID`s by arranging the `ALIAS_ID_CD` in order B>A>D>C. The only issue is that I would like to obtain only distinct `ID`'s for the `ALIAS_ID_CD` that's highest on my hierarchy.

For a subset of values:

```
ID  ALIAS_ID    ALIAS_ID_CD
1   A10         A
1   B10         B
1   C10         C
1   D10         D
2   D20         D
2   B20         B
2   C20         C
3   D30         D
3   A30         A
```

I'd like to the following returned:

```
ID  ALIAS_ID    ALIAS_ID_CD
1   B10         B
2   B20         B
3   A30         A
```

Comment: Hello Strawberry, I tried clearing it up, not familiar with the format system. Can you let me know if it makes more sense? Sorry to hear that you have diarrhea, hope you feel better

Comment: is `alias_id` unique within the table?

Comment: thanks for getting back. Yes it is

Comment: Generate a temp/virtual table (like as a CTE) containing your  desired priority and key, do a regular `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`.  Probably faster than using `CASE` or anything similar, too.

Comment: What I did was query all the `ID`'s and their `ALIAS_ID`'s by `ALIAS_ID_CD` into different temp tables (temp table A, B,C,D) and basically went through each temp table only retaining unique `ID` in order of preference (in this case B>A>D>C). But this process was a little too taxing, and not very intelligent... :/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                id
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      (m.id, m.alias_id) =
        (
        SELECT  mi.id, mi.alias_id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.id = md.id
        ORDER BY
                mi.id, mi.alias_id
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

**Update:**

In SQL Server, that would be:

```
SELECT  id, alias_id, alias_id_cd
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY alias_id) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Quassnoi, I don't really understand what this query is doing. you're selecting all distinct ID, but what comes after the join loses me. The command isn't working for me either.

Comment: I receive the following errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT' and Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Comment: @user3166881: your question is tagged `mysql` and those above are SQL Server errors.

Comment: ah. let me change that then. Apologies

Comment: OVER is not working :/ 

>[Error] Script lines: 21-27 ------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: @user3166881: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab16a/61)

```
SELECT ID, ALIAS_ID, ALIAS_ID_CD 
FROM (
   SELECT *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID 
                             ORDER BY 
                               ID, 
                               CASE ALIAS_ID_CD 
                                 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 
                                 WHEN 'A' THEN 2 
                                 WHEN 'C' THEN 3 
                                 WHEN 'D' THEN 4 
                               END,
                               ALIAS_ID
                           ) ROWNUM 
   FROM IDBANK
) SUB
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

What's important to realize here is that you've specified an ordering (e.g., B-A-C-D), which is different from standard ASCII ordering.  This is why the CASE statement is used.

The meat of the query is breaking the table into subsets (partition by ID) and applying a row number to correctly serialize the subsets (order by ...).  When that's complete, you only want to look at the first record in each subset -- this is why you must apply `WHERE ROWNUM=1` on the outer query.

Comment: I'm honestly at a loss here, why won't OVER work? Is that a function that exists in a new version of sql server? I'm receiving the following error:

[Error] Script lines: 1-14 -------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: @user3166881: 1) please remember to upvote helpful answers/comments.  2) what version of SQL Server are you using?  As you can tell by going to the link in my answer, `over` does work.  This was tested in both MS-SS 2008 and 2012.

Answer (score 0):

A slight bit simpler and less costly version:

```
select id, min(alias_id) as alias_id, min(alias_id_cd) AS alias_id_cd
from mytable
group by id
```

Makes data assumptions that like your sample data, if alias_id_cd is higher alphabetic order, it's higher in your hierarchy, and that the alias_id also represents a similar progression numerically.

Comment: For one thing, the OP doesn't want a standard ordering, so `MIN(...)` wouldn't work.  Additionally, the use of two aggregates is going to (probably) get unrelated rows.